# speaker name and action in direct speech

Tags: english, writing

I am trying to write a story in English, though English is not my mother language.

I would like to know if any of the two following lines is correct, and which is better:

"I talked to Bob," said Alice, "and he told me he is happy."

"I talked to Bob," Alice said, "and he told me he is happy."